# 3B - Body, Border и Background - рассогласование внутри Body

Tags: css

Доброго всем здравия.

Или я плохо учился, или что-то совсем непонятное происходит на проекте.  
Подробнее:
есть тег body у него в стилях есть

```
margin:0; padding:0px;
border:solid 1px #0000ff; background:#ddFFFF;
```

Но! Почему цвет бэкграунда во всю страницу, это и понятно, а вот бордер почему-то до конца контента.  
Как такое возможно?

Comment: Если почитать про background особых элементов в спецификации CSS, то можно выяснить следующее: у элементов html, body и canvas бесконечное полотно для прорисовки. Соответственно border рисуется вокруг отрисованной страницы, а background на всем бесконечном полотне.

["CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3" - 3.11 Backgrounds of Special Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут как раз все понятно от части. 
body обрамляет еще html, который делает overflow: visible или auto, не знаю точно. Но все же надо что-то типа такого:

```
body, html {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Добавлять к body и html `height:100%` не очень хорошая практика и может вызвать проблему в работе скриптов, если уж делать таким способом, то можно попробовать так: http://jsfiddle.net/81pb4jrf/

И не нужно забывать про `box-sizing: border-box;`, иначе контент будет всегда больше, чем 100%, по ширине и высоте.

Comment: добавлял я уже к html

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

Тогда происходит повторение background'а в body. Background у меня градиентный.  
Повторение происходит, если браузер свернуть в окно, например высотой в 400, 500 пикселей по высоте.
Градиент занимает 100% окна, а потом прокруткой если двигаться вниз, то background прокручивается столько раз, сколько входящего окна в целой странице.  
окно 300 px, высота контента 1000px, значит 3 раза.

Comment: @MasterAlex  
@binliz  
вот моя ситуация:  
http://jsfiddle.net/81pb4jrf/1/
________
Или так:  
http://jsfiddle.net/81pb4jrf/2/  
но тоже не вариант.    
background заканчивается вперёд контента.